# The integral over a four-dimensional closed curve

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

In Landau-Lifschitz (Volume 2)

> The integral over a four-dimensional closed curve is transformed into an integral over the surface spanning it by the substitution:
>   $$
> dx^i \rightarrow df^{ki}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.\tag{6.18}
> $$
>   Thus for the integral of a vector, we have:
>   $$
> \oint A_i dx^i=\int df^{ki}\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^k}
> =\frac{1}{2}\int df^{ik}\left(\frac{\partial A_k}{\partial x^i}-\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^k}\right).\tag{6.19}
> $$
>   which is generalization of Stokes' theorem.

How the antisymmetric tensor created at the end?/How is the last part obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the two-form $df^{ik}$ is antisymmetric, since $ df^{ik} = dx^i dx'^k - dx^k dx'^i$ (in their notation), so $df^{ik} = - df^{ki}$. Your identity follows after using this and relabeling indices.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is the area of the projection of a parallelogram on $x_i x_k$ coordinate planes.